# How to properly return a subset of object properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I just started playing with the WebAPI template in VS2017 ASP.NET Core using Entity Framework Core, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to return a subset of an object's properties for a particular Get request.

I used the built in scaffolding to generate a controller initially, and the `Get` request method it generated initially looked like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    return _context.People;
}
```

My problem was that `Person` has a child class that I don't want included when someone makes a call to `GetPeople()`.

Since I don't want to return an anonymous object, I instead added a stripped down class in the controller called `PersonInfo` that has only the properties I want to be returned, like this:

```
public class PersonInfo
{
    public int  id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string AD { get; set; }
}
```

and then I updated the `GetPeople()` method to this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<PersonInfo> GetPeople()
{
    List<PersonInfo> pi = new List<PersonInfo>();
    foreach(var person in _context.People
        .Select(p => new { p.id, p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.AD})
        .ToList())
    {
        PersonInfo newPerson = new PersonInfo();
        newPerson.id = person.id;
        newPerson.FirstName = person.FirstName;
        newPerson.LastName = person.LastName;
        newPerson.AD = person.AD;
        pi.Add(newPerson);
    }
    return pi;
}
```

This works fine, it just feels horribly inefficient. There's got to be a better way, right?

Comment: I didn't see the query and ToList hidden inside the `foreach`. Apart from efficiency, this is hard to read too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't disagree :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That indeed is horribly inefficient. The method should look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<PersonInfo>> GetPeople()
{
    return await _context.People
        // select the data you want directly
        .Select(p => new PersonInfo 
        { 
            id = p.id, 
            FirstName = p.FirstName, 
            LastName = p.LastName, 
            AD = p.AD
        })
        // always use the asynchronous version of EF Core extension methods
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

By the way, you should get used to using the `IActionResult` interface in ASP.NET Core. That allows you to easily customize the status code and how the data is returned. It's much more preferable to use something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPeople()
{
    var data = await _context.People
        // select the data you want directly
        .Select(p => new PersonInfo 
        { 
            id = p.id, 
            FirstName = p.FirstName, 
            LastName = p.LastName, 
            AD = p.AD
        })
        // always use the asynchronous version of EF Core extension methods
        .ToListAsync();

    return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: I didn't see that `ToList()` in that `foreach`! Not just inefficient, unreadable as well!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, I'm not a fan of putting linq queries in `foreach`s

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well now I guess I'm not either, I just didn't know any better ;)

Comment: It's not very FUNy, is it?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto VS isn't finding `Json`. Is there a namespace or assembly I need to reference?

Comment: @Bodacious Does the class inherit from `Controller`? Can it find `Ok()`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ah, no, it was inheriting from `ControllerBase`.